# How to get a number from list

Tags: python

could you pls help me with one easy think I believe but not for me
How can I get out just number from this

```
list = [{'id': 120 }]
```

many thank in advance

Comment: Do you know how to index a list? Do you know how to access a dictionary element by key? Do both of those together.

Comment: list[0]['id'] should give out the number

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you *also* demonstrate that you are working to solve your issue. The best way to do that in my opinion is to include the **text** based version of the source code you have so far, even if it is not working quite right. Also, please don't use `list` as a variable name. You clobber the type name if you do.

Answer (score -1):

Your code seems absurdal, it is one element dictionary in a list. TO access this element here, you need to use

```
list[0]["id"]
```

However, it seems as you much rather want the:

```
list=[("id",120)]
list[0][1]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why is a list of a single tuple much better than a list of a single dictionary?

Comment: I just think that he wanted this approach.